# Email Monitoring Service for Gmail, to automatically detect calendar events

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I'm looking for a service that will monitor your gmail inbox, and auto-detect calendar events. Gmail already does this, but I'd like it to go one step further, and automatically add these events to my google calendar, instead of merely suggesting I "quick add" it when I read the email. This would be something similar to Tripit, which monitors for flight information, but for all calendar events. Anyone know of something like this?

Thanks,
Yasyf

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at If This Then That (ifttt.com).  It allows you to automate all sorts of web tasks like this.  There are hundreds of pre-packaged recipes or you can roll your own

Comment: I've had a look there, but its not really what I was describing. I was more looking to some service that, once granted permission, will monitor your inbox and add the events automatically, based on the details it can detect.

Comment: @yasuf did you find an answer?